# How can I pull all the documents by starting and ending of the day for any given date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, momentjs

I submit a date to nodejs server in the following format

```
2018-11-02T00:36:00+05:30 // Actual time is 12:36AM
```

When I check the document in the database (studio 3T) the format looks like

```
2018-11-01T19:06:00.000Z // minus 5.30 hours from the actual time 12:36AM
```

Now the situation is that i have to search all the documents by starting and ending of the day for any given date.

How can I pull all the documents for the date `2018-11-02`

If I query to find the documents by start time and end time of `2018-11-02`  For Example with moment js start and end day:

I get today as `2018-11-01T18:30:00.000Z` and tomorrow as `2018-11-01T23:59:59.999Z`

What I tried

```
const today = req.body.date;
const tomorrow = moment(today).endOf('day').toISOString();

"startDate" : { "$gte": new Date(today), "$lt": new Date(tomorrow) }
// today is 2018-11-01T18:30:00.000Z tomorrow is 2018-11-01T23:59:59.999Z
```

It gives an incorrect end date.

Answer (score 0):

I have just add one day to the start day of the today in ISO Format

```
const today = moment(new Date(req.body.date)).startOf('day');
const tomorrow = moment(new Date(today)).add(1, 'days').toISOString();

"startDate" : { "$gte": new Date(today), "$lt": new Date(tomorrow) }
```